# Angular 2 How to "watch" for tab changes

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have:

```
<md-tab-group color="primary">
  <md-tab label="Проэкты">
    <h1>Some tab content</h1>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Обучалка">
    <h1>Some more tab content</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

I need to catch an event when a specific tab is clicked and call this function inside my component:

```
onLinkClick() {
  this.router.navigate(['contacts']); 
}
```

Comment: It seems like there is no `tabChanging` event to indicate the tab has just been clicked - to allow you to prepare for the change. This really ought to be a feature request :-) Like a 'tabGuard' similar to a lightweight route guard.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You could use the `(selectedTabChange)` *event*. Check [**Material2#tabs**](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api).

**Template:**

```
<mat-tab-group color="primary" (selectedTabChange)="onLinkClick($event)">
  ...
</mat-tab-group>
```

**Component**:

```
import { MatTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material';

// ...

onLinkClick(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
  console.log({ event });

  this.router.navigate(['contacts']); 
}
```

Comment: That's good, but with navigation tab, whitout <mat-tab-group> it's not working. There have event to get this event when we use directive mat-tab-nav-bar on nav element ?

Comment: import { MatTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material/tabs'; is the correct import as per the latest Angular Material modules

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the event as an `@Output` from you `md-tab` component.  Something like:

```
import { EventEmitter, Output, Input, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'tab',
    template: `
        <button (click)="clicked()">{{ name }}</button>
    `,
    styles: [`
    `]
})
export class TabComponent {
    @Input() name = 'replaceme';
    @Output() tabClicked = new EventEmitter<null>();

    clicked() {
        this.tabClicked.emit();
    }
}
```

Then you consume that event in the `md-tab-group`, something like this:

```
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'tab-group',
    template: `
        <!--<tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [name]="tab"></tab>-->
        <tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [name]="tab" (tabClicked)="tabChanged(tab)"></tab>
        <div>
        {{ selectedTab }}
        </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
    `]
})
export class TabGroupComponent {
    private tabs = ['foo', 'bar'];
    private selectedTab = this.tabs[0];

    onInit() {
        this.selectedTab = this.tabs[0];
    }

    tabChanged(tab) {
        this.selectedTab = tab;
    }
}
```

[Heres a working plunker that demonstrates the concept](http://plnkr.co/edit/kGjSYcHzAPhCQVHVixQx?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

it can be done easily as follows

```
 <md-tab-group color="primary" (click)="selectedTabIndex=tabRef.selectedIndex" #tabRef>
      <md-tab label="Проэкты">
        <h1>Some tab content</h1>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Обучалка">
        <h1>Some more tab content</h1>
        <p>...</p>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tab-group>
```

only thing to do is defining a global variable in your component.

```
 export class MyComponent implements OnInit{   
 selectedTabIndex=0;
     ngOnInit(){
         // 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Documentation says, that the content of the you tab is not injected into the DOM until the tab is activated. So, you may catch DOM events on you components with `@HostListener` annotation:

```
<md-tab-group color="primary">
  <md-tab label="Проэкты">
    <my-cool-tab1></my-cool-tab1>
  </md-tab>
  ...
</md-tab-group>
```

Component:

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cool-tab1', ...})
export class MyCoolTab1Component {

  @HostListener('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument')
  foo() {
    console.log('Tab activated');
  }

  @HostListener('DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument')
  foo2() {
    console.log('Tab deactivated');
  }
}
```

update: this not works in FF %(

Answer (score -3):

You can use **ngKeypress** ( Angular Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress)) into any HTML tag.
For example:

```
<anyHtmlTag ng-keypress="yourFunction($event)">  

yourFunction(evt){
   if(evt.code === "Tab"){
      //Do your stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: This question is about `Angular`, not `AngularJs`.