# Angular pass name of label

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<div class="content">
  <md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="label1" (click)="passSourceOfDocuments()">
      <details *ngFor="let package of documentPackages">
        <summary>{{package.documentPackageGuid}}</summary>
        <ul>
          <details *ngFor="let doc of package.Documents">
            <summary>{{doc.documentGuid}}</summary>
              ..........
          </details>
        </ul>
      </details>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="label2" (click)="passSourceOfDocuments()">
      <details *ngFor="let doc of emaildocuments">
             ......................
      </details>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
</div>
```

I would pass name of label in function "passSourceOfDocuments()" it is possible ? Can I bind this label with property in .ts file ?

Comment: Do you want to acces it's value or the element itself?

Comment: @Vega I want have acces only to label value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can add a 'template reference variable' to each of your `<md-tab>` elements, then you could refer to them in the function like this,

```
<md-tab #tab1 label="label1" (click)="passSourceOfDocuments(tab1.textLabel)">
<md-tab #tab2 label="label2" (click)="passSourceOfDocuments(tab2.textLabel)">
```

Or if you have an array of labels declared as a property in the component file, then you can add them by index or some similar means,

> component

```
labelsArr = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'];
```

> template

```
<md-tab [label]="labelsArr[0]" (click)="passSourceOfDocuments(labelsArr[0])">
<md-tab [label]="labelsArr[1]" (click)="passSourceOfDocuments(labelsArr[1])">
```

Comment: it's looks nice but when i click on tab function don't execute in .ts file  i use passSourceOfDocuments(info:any) {
    console.log(info);
 }

Comment: are you using the first approach? If so, are you able to see if the method is being executed at all when clicked on a md-tab?

Comment: @amal i change event and place now i use <md-tab-group (selectChange)="onLinkClick($event)"> it's work

Comment: Okay, makes sense.

Comment: @user370486 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059151/angular-2-how-to-watch-for-tab-changes/42059318 maybe this help