# in angular mat how can i get previously selected mat-tab in component even after exploring other components ? without using localstorage and service?

Tags: angular, mat-tab

Maintaining selected mat-tab state across Angular components without using localStorage or service

Question:
I'm working on an Angular application where I have multiple components containing mat-tab-group. I want to preserve the selected tab state when navigating between these components. I've already implemented a solution using local Storage and a service, but I'm looking for an alternative method that doesn't involve these approaches.

Here's the specific behavior I'm trying to achieve:

Select a tab in Component A.
Navigate to Component B.
Return to Component A, and the previously selected tab should remain selected instead of defaulting to the first tab.
I've tried to to manage it with flag(true , false) but it still defaults to the first tab. How can I achieve this without using localStorage or a service? Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can u please provide me code in stackblitz?

Comment: yes please follow this steps 
below is my 
demo code 
can you please explain it in this code?

step 1: select the plant tab 
step 2 : click on nevigate to test component button 
step 3 : ack to dashboard 
i don't get plant tab selected i want it selected

https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/Pranav12333/angular-multiple-component-tabselection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular How to catch mat-tab changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589504/angular-how-to-catch-mat-tab-changed-event)

Answer (score 0):

[Angular How to catch mat-tab changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589504/angular-how-to-catch-mat-tab-changed-event)

You can do it with `MatTabChangeEvent`.
I think I understood something similar. Can you please check it?

Comment: hello sir i have already tried it here below is my 
demo code 
can you please explain it in this code?

step 1: select the plant tab 
step 2 : click on nevigate to test component button 
step 3 : ack to dashboard 
i don't get plant tab selected i want it selected

https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/Pranav12333/angular-multiple-component-tabselection

Comment: Workspace does not exist